# How can I call a JavaScript function through html button?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want from the html component part, call a JavaScript file to run a command, clicking on a button.

But when I click the button nothing happens:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

</head>
<body>

<p id="counter">Loading button click data.</p>


<button  id="buttonForScraping">begin to scrape!</button>
<script>
  function startScrape(){
    jQuery.ajax({
      type:'get',
      url:'../../../scraping.js',
      data:[],
      dataType:'json',
      success: function(rs)
      {},
      failure : function(rs)
      {}
    });
  }
</script>
</body>

</html>

This is the html code, and the js file is : 


const {exec}  = require('child_process');
const button = window.document.getElementById('buttonForScraping');
button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

exec('scrapy crawl address', (err, stdout, stderr) => {


  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
  console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);

});});
```

The scrapy command is a Python command, so I need to make an ajax call to run it on the server, I think.

Comment: As this isn't related to Angular, I have removed the tag. I suggest you use the correct ones to reach the maximum amount of people that can help you !

Comment: You can't access the browser API and the server API at the same time from the same code.

Comment: you can use onClick method to your html button to call a js function.

Comment: sorry i have forgotten to call the function, but it still doesn't work, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To run code on the serverside, you actually need a server to answer requests. That could look like this:

```
const { exec }  = require('child_process');
const app = require("express")(); // "npm install express" to install this dependency

app.get("/adress", (req, res) => { // server this path
 exec('scrapy crawl address', (err, stdout, stderr) => {

   res.json({ // respond to client if the command was done
     stdout: "" + stdout,
     stderr: "" + stderr
   });

});

app.listen(80,() => console.log("server started"));
```

That will open a server on port 80 if you start the script with `node ./scrapping.js`, and respond with JSON if you visit it on http://localhost/adress

Now whenever the button gets clicked on the frontend, you have to start an aJAX request to the backend:

```
// "async" lets us write callbacks more gracefully
button.addEventListener('click', async function(e) {
 try {
  // fetch is like $.ajax, but its native
  // 'await' is like a callback
  const { stdout, stderr } = await fetch("http://localhost/adress").then(res => res.json());
   console.log(stdout, stderr);
 } catch(err) {
   console.error("error occured while pinging server", err);
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To execute a JavaScript function when clicking a button, you can use a [sample like this](https://plnkr.co/edit/PqQhIOMmBGT3qx2Rjww9?p=preview).

First, create the HTML button and use the onClick():

```
<button onClick="doSomething()">Button Text</button>
```

The onClick() tells the browser to execute a JavaScript function.  Now in the JavaScript file put create your function:

```
function doSomething() {
  alert('do something');
  console.log('do something ')
}
```

This simple function outputs to the console log and throws an alert, but functions can get a lot more complex than that.

To execute a server side method or python command from an HTML page, you're going to have to need a more complex architecture probably.

Answer (score -1):

You have to include the js file into the html file like in the example.
**Note:** Make sure the path of the js file is correct in `src` attribute of `script`.
`<script src ="myScript.js"></script>`